# How do you filter JSON data using axios and useEffect?

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios, react-hooks, expo

I want to filter the data from this json file:

```
Array(53)
0: {fips: "02", country: "US", state: "AK", county: null, level: "state", …}
1: {fips: "01", country: "US", state: "AL", county: null, level: "state", …}
2: {fips: "05", country: "US", state: "AR", county: null, level: "state", …}
3: {fips: "04", country: "US", state: "AZ", county: null, level: "state", …}
4: {fips: "06", country: "US", state: "CA", county: null, level: "state", …}
5: {fips: "08", country: "US", state: "CO", county: null, level: "state", …}
6: {fips: "09", country: "US", state: "CT", county: null, level: "state", …}
7: {fips: "11", country: "US", state: "DC", county: null, level: "state", …}
8: {fips: "10", country: "US", state: "DE", county: null, level: "state", …}
9: {fips: "12", country: "US", state: "FL", county: null, level: "state", …}
10: {fips: "13", country: "US", state: "GA", county: null, level: "state", …}
11: {fips: "15", country: "US", state: "HI", county: null, level: "state", …}
12: {fips: "19", country: "US", state: "IA", county: null, level: "state", …}
13: {fips: "16", country: "US", state: "ID", county: null, level: "state", …}
14: {fips: "17", country: "US", state: "IL", county: null, level: "state", …}
15: {fips: "18", country: "US", state: "IN", county: null, level: "state", …}
16: {fips: "20", country: "US", state: "KS", county: null, level: "state", …}
17: {fips: "21", country: "US", state: "KY", county: null, level: "state", …}
18: {fips: "22", country: "US", state: "LA", county: null, level: "state", …}
19: {fips: "25", country: "US", state: "MA", county: null, level: "state", …}
20: {fips: "24", country: "US", state: "MD", county: null, level: "state", …}

0:
actuals: {cases: 65944, deaths: 318, positiveTests: 107163, negativeTests: 2044164, contactTracers: 235, …}
annotations: {cases: {…}, deaths: {…}, positiveTests: {…}, negativeTests: {…}, contactTracers: {…}, …}
country: "US"
county: null
fips: "02"
lastUpdatedDate: "2021-04-21"
lat: null
level: "state"
locationId: "iso1:us#iso2:us-ak"
long: null
metrics: {testPositivityRatio: 0.030363378437363597, testPositivityRatioDetails: {…}, caseDensity: 22.164440621268295, contactTracerCapacityRatio: 0.28986784140969163, infectionRate: 0.968046978543, …}
population: 731545
riskLevels: {overall: 2, testPositivityRatio: 1, caseDensity: 2, contactTracerCapacityRatio: 1, infectionRate: 1, …}
state: "AK"
url: "https://covidactnow.org/us/alaska-ak"
```

How can I use axios and React Hooks to filter this data and only get the state name and their actuals as variables to pass in a search UI later?

This is my code currently:

```
useEffect(() => {
        
        axios.get('https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/states.json?apiKey={apiKey}')
      
        .then(response => {
          return response.data;
          })
          .then(responseData => {
            console.log(responseData)
          })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }, []);
```

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you want to do. Are you asking how to save this information using `useState`, for example? Or do you just need to know how to filter out all of the other data besides those two fields so that you get an array of *just* state names and actuals?

Comment: Yes, I would like to use `useState` to save this information to variables, so I can pass it later on to a UI component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [data,setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {      
        axios.get('https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/states.json?apiKey={apiKey}')
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(responseData => {
            setData(responseData)
          })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }, []);
```

I'd note that there probably isn't a reason to try to get rid of the other fields. You *could* just save the entire response using `setData`.

After the `useEffect` runs, `data` will be filled with an array that you can access in your component.

---

**Update, based on comments:**

To filter just *one* state's data out, you might do something like this:

```
const [stateData, setStateData] = useState();

//...

.then(responseData => {
  setStateData(responseData.filter(i => i.state === stateName)[0])            
})
```

Then, you could access the individual properties by doing:

```
stateData.actuals
stateData.deaths
```

If you wanted to do this while keeping all of the other API data (so that you could change states, for instance, without doing another call, it might look something like this):

```
const [stateName, setStateName] = useState("AK");
const [data,setData] = useState([]);
const [stateData, setStateData] = useState();

useEffect(() => {      
        axios.get('https://api.covidactnow.org/v2/states.json?apiKey={apiKey}')
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(responseData => {
            setData(responseData)
          })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      }, []);

useEffect(() => {
  setStateData(data.filter(i => i.state === stateName)[0]) 
},[data, stateName])
```

*Note: I'm not doing any error checking yet for whether [0] exists -- you may want to have a case for if the data doesn't exist*

Comment: Hi, your answer works, but it only answers some parts of my question. Instead of filling `data` with an array, I want it to be a variable. For example, if I select the first index of the array, which is `{fips: "02", country: "US", state: "AK", county: null, level: "state", …}`, I want to go into that actuals of that index, fetch the cases and deaths, and store them as separate variables.

Comment: Okay — do you know how to access the first item of an array? Like using data[0]?

Comment: Yes, I know in a basic sense.

Comment: Okay — so you can access individual elements by doing data[0].actuals If you need more than that, help me understand how you’re using it  and I can try to write more details for your case.

Comment: Sure, I can tell you my whole case. Basically, I have retrieved the user's location and have stored their state/province name in a variable, `stateName`. I want to use this `stateName` variable, and filter out the Array only filtering that state's actuals. I then want to go inside that specific state's actuals and retrieve the cases and deaths. Finally, I'd like to store them as separate variables

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! It looks like it works, however, there is an error for typescript. I'm a bit of a beginner in typescript, but the error is Property 'state' does not exist on type 'never'. Have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: You would have to show the line where this is happening, but I assume it's probably because you need to notate your `useState` with types (like `useState<MyType>`). This may be outside of the scope of this question if you're not familiar with how to define types or interfaces yet and would make a good new question. If it's an easy fix, I can do it here. When you're ready, this answer can be accepted by clicking the green checkmark.

Comment: Yes, if you don't mind, could you tell me the notation type for `useState` in order to match the property `state`?

Comment: If you mean the `state` field (eg the one that has "AK", "AL", etc), it would just be `useState<string | undefined>`. If you mean an *entire* row of the original array (with the actuals, deaths, etc), it'll be much lengthier -- you need to define each possible property.

Comment: Thank you! Got it working now. So, you would just pass in `stateData.cases` in the UI, correct? For example, ```return ( <Text>{stateData.cases}</Text> )```

Comment: Yes. Just keep in mind that on first render, that will be undefined, since `useEffect` won't have finished running yet. So, you'll probably want to check to see if you have a value before rendering it.